# samsung galaxy core-i8262 /system/xbin/su path

Tags: rooting, sd-card, samsung-galaxy-core-2

I have **samsung gt-i8262** phone.

**scenario**: i want to drop **superSU** binary for gaining root access. I tried *framaroot* but was not successful. now I am using cydia impactor to execute script as `/system/xbin/su`. 
There are two partition `sdcard0` and `exsdcard` in file explorer, a format which i have not seen in other devices.

**my problem:** How can I know the path of xbin? is it the same in gt-i8262 device as the other devices.
NOTE: later on, I want to root this device and install CWM recovery.

any expert help would be appreciated. 
Thanks in advance, gud day.

Comment: `/system/xbin/su` is an absolute path, it can only be in one location. Do you have a reason to believe that the path is incorrect? Are you having trouble rooting your device properly?

Comment: yes, i do have reason. Whole internet is able to root gt-i8262 with `framaroot` where as i am not. I rooted other devices n never faced any trouble. When i hit `# drop SuperSU su to /system/xbin/su` in `cydia impactor`, i get unknown error.